# ODE $y'=(a \cos y +b \sin y -1)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some hints for solving differential equation
$$y'=(a \cos y +b \sin  y -1)^2,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are real constants and $y$ is function of one parameter.
It apeard as solution of certain problem, and I would like to generate some examples other than trivialone $(a=b=0)$. If someone is familiar with this kind of ODE, I would be very grateful for any information. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That's a [separable differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Probably, the easiest would be to write
$$x'=\frac{1}{(a \cos (y)+b \sin (y)-1)^2}$$ and use the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$.

This would give for the rhs
$$\int\frac {2(1+t^2)}{\big((a+1) t^2-2 b t+1-a\big)^2}\,dt=\frac 2{(a+1)^2}\int\frac {1+t^2}{(t-r_1)^2(t-r_2)^2}$$ and partial fraction decomposition leads to simple integrals.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: @Claude Lebovici, a great hint but it should be $y'$ on LHAS in place of $x'$.

Comment: I think that LHS in  suggestion is good. $$\frac{d y}{d x}=(a \cos y+ b\sin y-1)^2 \rightarrow \frac{d x}{d y}=(a \cos y+ b\sin y-1)^{-2} $$

Comment: @ZReiner. This is exactly want I meant. Since you used $y'$, I then used $x'$

Answer (score 0):

Following Lebovici's Hint,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(a \cos y+ b\sin y-1)^2.~~~(1)$$
Let us take $$y=2\tan^{-1}{v} =\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{1+v^2} \frac{dv}{dx}.$$
Eq. (1) becomes
Following @Claude Lebovici,
$$\frac{2}{1+v^2} \frac{dv}{dx}= [a \cos (2 \tan^{-1} v) + b \sin (2 \tan^{-1} v)-1]^2$$ $$=[a \cos^2(\tan^{-1}{v})+ 1- a \sin^2(\tan^{-1} v) + 2b \sin (\tan^{-1} v) \cos (\tan^{-1}v)-1]^2$$
$$\implies \frac{2}{1+v^2} \frac{dv}{dx}=
\left(\frac{a}{1+v^2}-\frac{av^2}{1+v^2}+\frac{2bv}{1+v^2}-1\right)^2.$$
$$\implies \int \frac{(1+v^2)~dv}{[(1+a)v^2-2bv+1-a]^2} dv =\int dx$$
Using  Matnematica, we get
$$\frac{1}{1-a^2-b^2}\left( \frac{b-(1+a)v}{(1+a)v^2-2bv+1-a}\right)-$$ $$\frac{1}{2(1-a^2-b^2)^{3/2}} \left( (1-a) \tan^{-1} \frac{(a+1)v-b}{\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}}\right). =x+C, ~where~ v=\tan(y/2)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Too bad, we can't get the function $y$ explicitly.

Comment: @ZReiner Oh! here you are getting $x$ as a function of $y$. Getting $y$ as a function will not be possible.